# MySQL: OR in SHOW TABLES?

Tags: mysql

I've just installed MySQL and wondering if `SHOW TABLES` output can be combined. Btw, I'm not a DBA, please be patient if this question doesn't make sense to you. I just want to know how SQL query works, and what not.

E.g.

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+---------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_information_schema          |
+---------------------------------------+
| CHARACTER_SETS                        | 
| COLLATIONS                            | 
| COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY | 
| COLUMNS                               | 
| COLUMN_PRIVILEGES                     | 
| KEY_COLUMN_USAGE                      | 
| PROFILING                             | 
| ROUTINES                              | 
| SCHEMATA                              | 
| SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES                     | 
| STATISTICS                            | 
| TABLES                                | 
| TABLE_CONSTRAINTS                     | 
| TABLE_PRIVILEGES                      | 
| TRIGGERS                              | 
| USER_PRIVILEGES                       | 
| VIEWS                                 | 
+---------------------------------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Certain column can be filtered with `LIKE`

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES LIKE 'SCHEMATA';
+-----------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_information_schema (SCHEMATA) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| SCHEMATA                                | 
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Instead of typing this one by one ...

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES LIKE 'TABLES';  
+---------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_information_schema (TABLES) |
+---------------------------------------+
| TABLES                                | 
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I was wondering if `SHOW TABLES` output can be filtered with more than 1 parameter.

Probably something like `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'SCHEMATA' or 'TABLES';`, but this query doesn't work

Desired Output

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_information_schema            |
+-----------------------------------------+
| SCHEMATA                                | 
| TABLES                                  | 
+-----------------------------------------+
```

**Update:**

I've just noticed that `SHOW TABLES` also can be produced with `SELECT` statement

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'information_schema';            
+---------------------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME                            |
+---------------------------------------+
| CHARACTER_SETS                        | 
| COLLATIONS                            | 
| COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY | 
| COLUMNS                               | 
| COLUMN_PRIVILEGES                     | 
| KEY_COLUMN_USAGE                      | 
| PROFILING                             | 
| ROUTINES                              | 
| SCHEMATA                              | 
| SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES                     | 
| STATISTICS                            | 
| TABLES                                | 
| TABLE_CONSTRAINTS                     | 
| TABLE_PRIVILEGES                      | 
| TRIGGERS                              | 
| USER_PRIVILEGES                       | 
| VIEWS                                 | 
+---------------------------------------+
17 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Still didn't work

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'information_schema' and TABLE_NAME = 'SCHEMATA' or 'TABLES';             
+------------+
| TABLE_NAME |
+------------+
| SCHEMATA    | 
+------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' 
  AND TABLE_NAME IN ('TABLES', 'SCHEMATA');
```

or, for example (6 tables will be shown)

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' 
  AND (    TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TABLE%'
        OR TABLE_NAME LIKE 'SCHEMA%' );
```